# Cannot find USB splitter (1 female -> 2 male) where both males handle DATA

Tags: usb, microphone, usb-3

I have 2 PCs side-by-side behind my desk. One is for work, the other for personal stuff. I have 1 inexpensive-but-perfect USB mic. It works great with both PCs BUT I can only use it in 1 pc at a time. To switch it to the other PC I have to go back behind my desk, pull out the USB from one pc and plug it into the other. Super pain, especially since I'm in a temporary wheelchair due to sports injury.

I'm trying to avoid buying a 2nd mic and have two mics sitting here on my desk.

At first the solution seemed simple: buy a 1-female to 2-male USB splitter. And yes, you can find these everywhere, including Amazon and Ebay. The problem is that almost all of them have only 1 male that works with data and 1 male that is charging only. I don't need charging - I need to use 1 mic on both PCs. I use a KVM switch to go between computers, it works great, but it doesn't have a mic jack.

I see a message similar to this all over the place on the USB splitters:

> "Both 2 splitter USB Male can charge, but only one usb male can data
> transfer."

I did find [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T1J9WNV) on Amazon that supports data on both males, but you have to flip a switch to go between males (only does data 1 at a time, not both), and this cable is so short that I cannot reach the switch without climbing behind my desk, and I may as well pull the usb from 1 pc and insert it in the other, if I'm going to do that, it's the same amount of trouble.

I'm looking for something simple and under $20. It seems nobody makes a splitter with data on both males in which both data males are active at the same time. As far as shortness of cable length, I'm happy to buy a USB extender, but in the example mentioned above, the extender wouldn't help because the switch will still be close to the computers and not close to me - unless I instead buy 2 extenders, 1 for each male, and maybe that is my only option. But that would mean buying 3 cables for this simple thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a usb extension cable for the one you found on amazon, this way you can locate the switch to a more convenient place. That or use a USB Hub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB cannot be split that way.
Your example splitters are designed so twice the power can be pulled from the host to one device, for higher-power equipment, & not to enable two devices to be connected.

One device can connect to one host at a time. You need a switch not a split. Google/Amazon/eBay is loaded with them - search "USB switch".

If you need to bring it closer, then you will need extension cables.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look for a USB switch.